# Turn 3 columns in a Query

Tags: sql, excel

What would be the best way to take 3 columns like so:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

and turn it into a query for SQL like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_code_amulet] ([item_id], [item_code], [item_name])
    VALUES (0, N'iabba01', N'Fire Parsal AppendixA')
```

I tried it with EXCEL formulas, but can't seem to get it right. Anyone here that can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually do this as by typing in the expression in one cell, say A1 (it can be any unused cell):

```
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_code_amulet] ([item_id], [item_code], [item_name])  VALUES ([ii], [ic], [in]);
```

And then using `REPLACE()` for the formulas:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE($A$1, '[ii]', A3), '[ic]', B3), '[in]', C3)
```

And then copy this formula down.

Why do I use this method?  First, I find it much easier to see what is happening by looking at the original formula.  A bunch of string concatenations makes it harder for me to understand the logic.

Second, it is very easy to change the formula.  If you have seen code that I've written in SQL, I am very particular about indentation, for instance.  When generating SQL in a spreadsheet, I'm often fiddling with the code so it looks right.

A third reason is that the same value can be used easily in multiple places in the SQL, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First Excel row (looks like row 3 from screenshot)

```
="INSERT [dbo].[tbl_code_amulet] ([item_id], [item_code], [item_name]) VALUES ("&A3&", '"&SUBSTITUTE(B3,"'","''")&"', '"&SUBSTITUTE(C3,"''","''")&"')"
```

then drag through the other rows.

**How I built it**

In Excel formulas, you build strings (text tockens)by double quoting (`"`) the text.
This means, the piece

```
"INSERT [dbo].[tbl_code_amulet] ([item_id], [item_code], [item_name]) VALUES ("
```

is equivalent to wrinting the text between the double quotes.

You need to know Excel let's you concatenate strings ith the `&` operator, that is `"Hello " & "World"` is equivalent to the string "Hello World".

You also need to remember strings need to be single quoted (`'`) in SQL commands
Your sencond and third column contain text data (strings) that means they have to be surrounded with `'`, which explanins the `, '` piece of code on the right hand side of the `VALUES` keyboard.

Finally, in SQL, you must escape a single quotes inside your text by doubling them. To achive this result, I ask Excel to replace each `'` with `''` by using the `SUBSTITUTE` function (see [official help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332))

Comment: Depending on your Excel/System options, you may need to replace `,` with `;` in `SUSTITUTE` function. Proposed formula works fine for me